# How to parse json file that content value/object via http url

Tags: python, json, api, http, url

I think my questions below different and im not able to find problem similar like mine...
I have json file (scanner.json) content values of nodes and links below

```
{
  "nodes": [
    "node1",
    "node2",
    "node3",
    "node4",
    "node5",
    "node6",
    "node7"
  ],
  "links": [
    [
      "node1",
      "node2",
      "120"
    ],
    [
      "node1",
      "node3",
      "120"
    ],
    [
      "node1",
      "node4",
      "120"
    ],
    [
      "node2",
      "node3",
      "120"
    ],
    [
      "node2",
      "node7",
      "120"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to pass the values of nodes and links to NBI API below

```
Request URL: http://172.18.10.10:6233/cv/api/scanner
Body:
{
  "channel": "scanner",
  "action": "create_device",
  "table": "U2",
  "nodes::[
    {
      "node_hostname": "node1",
    {,
    {
      "node_hostname": "node2",
    },
    {
      "node_hostname": "node3"
    }
  "links": [
    {
      "source_hostname": "node1",
      "dest_hostname": "node2",
      "matric": "120",
    },
  ]
 }
```

How can I do that? parse and send via http url the content of the json file above to NBI API above.
Please assist and advise me. Thank you

Comment: Hi there, this looks like you ask 'can you please write some code to fix my problem'. StackOverflow is meant for programmers asking assistance for their code, not for programmers asking for code period.

Comment: Hi...Im not asking people to write for me but if people do want to write and help me i would be much appreciated... I'm looking solution of my problem...they can provide me ref or guideline or even as u said...provide line of code that i can tune and adapt.  How can I enhance my knowledge alone...I need expert ..someone who kind heart to help...I know u are one of them who response to my questions..meaning that u care about my issue above...thank you...Anyway...I still hope someone could assist me further, Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just not how it works.

Comment: Thank you sir. Perhaps someone else could lead me the way...I believed stackoverflow can help me out. If not ...i accept it...anyway thank you sir.

Comment: Break it into few steps. 1) Write code that loads the JSON file into a python dictionary - search the web and find the solution. 2)  Learn how to traverse the dictionary from step 1 and modify it. Post the code here if you are facing issues.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your response and your advise. I appreciate it.